# Is there an equivalent of "global variables" in a React component? I'm trying to detect if the page has been refreshed or not and act accordingly

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I would like to have a boolean `hasReloaded` variable in my component.
I was thinking I could use an empty useEffect like so:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    hasReloaded = true;
  }, []);
```

as a way to detect if the page has been refreshed. Then I could use a conditional and if the page has reloaded, act accordingly and set it back to false:

```
    if (hasReloaded && page == 1) {
      hasReloaded = false;
      grid.purgeInfiniteCache();
    }
```

On a side note, I am running into issues with ag-grid where if I refresh the page when I've paginated over to page 2 or greater, once the page has reloaded, page 1 of the table shows the same results as the page I reloaded on. So I'm trying to detect if the page has reloaded and purge the cache in that event. I'm not sure if it's an ag-grid quirk or if there's something else I'm missing, but this is the best I've came up with for now.

Otherwise, is this a bad approach to detecting a refresh in general, and should I go about it a different way?